# jquery Datatables plugin: custom message per page when table is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I am using the [DataTables plugin](http://www.datatables.net/index) on multiple pages of my site and when no records are found I need it to display a different message on each page.

Right Now I use the below for the current message:

```
"oLanguage": {
        "sEmptyTable": "There is no data available for the week selected."
}
```

Is there some way to maybe put a conditional statement inside of oLanguage that checks for the current page?  Something like:

```
if (currentPage == "thisPage")
    "sEmptyTable" : "There is no data on this current page"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this trick works with Datatables, but you could try to pass the "sEmptyTable" as a function:

```
"oLanguage": {
    "sEmptyTable": function(){ return "There is no data"; }
}
```

See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tRTkd/ for a demo that sets the text of a button.

Comment: Worked great!  Thanks! I just created the function, did the logic in the function, and called it from "sEmptyTable".